# Beamer itemize: when changing an item to a figure item alert doesn't work

Tags: beamer, lists, itemize

I did a presentation, where I have an "animated" list, with the current item showing in red. After showing the last item I want to change the last item to a figure, to have a more picturesque way of talking about that last item. My problem is that with the last item I couldn't get the alert to work.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Minimal working example}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item[]<2-|alert@2> A,

            \item[]<3-|alert@3> b,

            \item[]\only<4|alert@4>{ and c.} \only<5>{ \missingfigure[figheight=0.4\textheight]{Picture of c.}}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This generates a [five page pdf](http://fbence.web.elte.hu/mwe.pdf) and what I would want is that on the fourth page, when the "and c." shows up, the "and c." should be red, but it is not. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
        \item<4-|alert@4>[]%
        \only<4>{and c.}%
        \only<5>{\missingfigure[figheight=0.4\textheight]{Picture of c.}}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! Two questions though. a) Why did you comment the end of the lines? b) What's the logic here? The <4-|alert@4> after \item is applied to everything until the next \item?

Comment: a) Don't worry. In this case, it does not matter. But some times we need to end the line with `%`.